# Convert MySQL query to LinQ

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have this MySQL query: (This is a working query)

```
SELECT cash.cash_id, cash.cash_name, articles_cellars.cellar_name, cash_status.cashstatus_name, 
            CASE cash.cashstatus_id
               WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT_WS(' ', users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname)
               WHEN 2 THEN '[No Asignado]'
            END AS user_name,
            CASE cash.cashstatus_id
               WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cashtransactionstatus_id IN (1,3) THEN cashtransaction_amount END) -
                                   SUM(CASE WHEN cashtransactionstatus_id IN (2,4,5) THEN cashtransaction_amount END)
                                FROM cash_transactions 
                                    WHERE cashpaymenttype_id = 1
                                    AND cash_transactions.cashopeningassignment_id = cash_openings_assignments.cashopeningassignment_id)
               WHEN 2 THEN 0.00
            END AS cashtransaction_amount
    FROM cash
    LEFT JOIN articles_cellars USING(cellar_id)
    LEFT JOIN cash_status USING(cashstatus_id)
    LEFT JOIN cash_openings_assignments USING(cash_id)
    LEFT JOIN users USING(user_id);
```

I need to know if exists any tool for convert automatically this statement to a C# LinQ.

My current LinQ:

```
var LINQFilter =  from Cash in _DataTable_Cash.AsEnumerable()
join Cellars in _DataTable_Cellars.AsEnumerable()
  on Cash.Field<Int32>("cellar_id") equals Cellars.Field<Int32>("cellar_id")

join CashStatus in _DataTable_CashStatus.AsEnumerable()
  on Cash.Field<Int32>("cashstatus_id") equals CashStatus.Field<Int32>("cashstatus_id")

join CashOpeningsAssignments in _DataTable_CashOpeningsAssignments.AsEnumerable().Where(a => (a.Field<Int32>("cashopeningassignmentstatus_id") == 1 || a.Field<Int32>("cashopeningassignmentstatus_id") == 2)) // 1 Open ,2 Reopened Assignments
  on Cash.Field<Int32>("cash_id") equals CashOpeningsAssignments.Field<Int32>("cash_id") into into_cashopeningsassignments
from CashOpeningsAssignments in into_cashopeningsassignments.DefaultIfEmpty()

join Users in _DataTable_Users.AsEnumerable()
  on (CashOpeningsAssignments == null ? 0 : CashOpeningsAssignments.Field<Int32>("user_id")) equals Users.Field<Int32>("user_id") into into_users
from Users in into_users.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new 
{
    cash_id = Cash.Field<Int32>("cash_id"),
    cellar_name = Cellars.Field<String>("cellar_name"),
    cash_name = Cash.Field<String>("cash_name"),
    cashstatus_name = CashStatus.Field<String>("cashstatus_name"),
    user_name = (Users == null ? "[No Asignado]" : Users.Field<String>("user_firstname") + (Char)32 + Users.Field<String>("user_lastname")),
    cashtransaction_amount = 0.00 // Sum Problem
};
```

But i have problems getting the `cashtransaction_amount`

Comment: Converting SQL to Linq is something like a Perl code obfuscation contest :D

Comment: You can run raw SQL queries in EF if that's what you're using so if you know the code already works just use it. Otherwise ask a much more specific question about a particular part of the conversion.

Comment: Hy @BenjaminGruenbaum i need to get the `cashtransaction_amount` column result